# Find the number of integers $n$ of the form $30a0b03$ that are divisible by $13$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, problem-solving

> Find the number of integers $n$ of the form $30a0b03$ that are divisible by $13$.

**What I Tried**: This problem looks simple but I cannot find it's solution. I recalled all the divisible rules of $13$ and tried to put them here, but none of them really worked. One thing which I got was :-
$$\rightarrow 13 | bo3 - 0a0 + 3$$
I only got this by applying one divisibility rule of $13$.
I might try and test for each values of $a$ and $b$ but there will be $100$ configurations, and I don't want to do that.

Can anyone help me?

**Edit**: After the hints @Daniel gave me, I figured out the solution and found $7$ solutions, can anyone tell me if this is correct or not?

Comment: $13 \mid 1001$, hence $13 \mid 3006003$. That leaves with about ten cases to handle.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but in the original number the middle term is $0$ , whereas here the middle term is $6$.

Comment: For $a =0$ look at $3006003 - 30a0b03$, for $a > 0$ look at $30a0b03 - 3006003$. And recall that you can ignore trailing zeros, so you're dealing with two- or three-digit numbers.

Comment: Actually we are dealing with 4 or 5 digit numbers, that did not make elegant. For $a = 0$ I found $b = 8$ a solution, but for $a > 0$ there are a lot of cases.

Comment: You didn't ignore trailing zeros. For $a > 0$ you should look at $(a-1)\cdot 10^2 + 40 + b$.

Comment: Oh ok I got it, still a bit tedious, but not now as I have got a pattern for $(a,b)$ , I figured it out.

Comment: I don't think that $13 | 99b - 100a + 6$ is correct.

Comment: I got $13 | b03-0a0+3$.

Comment: Oh right, I was wrong, nvm I will edit it, it dosen't matter now as I solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For four or more digit numbers, we do have a divisibility test by $13$ owing to $1001$ being divisible by $13$ ie, $1000$ leaving remainder $-1$. One checks the alternating sum of blocks of three consecutive digits. Eg, $\overline{abcdefgh}$ is divisible by $13$ if $\overline{ab}-\overline{cde}+\overline{fgh}$ is.

So we check how many $n$ there for which following is multiple of $13$ $$\overline{3}-\overline{0a0}+\overline{b03}=\overline{(b-1)(10-a)6}$$

We have $130+26=156$ one such number $\Rightarrow b=2$, $a=5$.

Others can be found by adding/subtracting $130$.

Answer (score 1):

You can crunch it out like this:

$$3\cdot 10^6+a\cdot 10^4 + b\cdot 100 + 3 \equiv 3\cdot(-3)^6+a\cdot (-3)^4 + b\cdot 9 + 3 \pmod{13}.$$

Note that $3^3 = 27 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ so the above is $\equiv 3+3a+9b+3 \pmod{13},$ which you want to be congruent to $0$.  That reduced to

$$3a+9b \equiv 7 \equiv 33 \pmod{13}$$

or

$$a+3b \equiv 11 \pmod{13}.$$

You can solve this congruence for $b$ for each value of $a = 0,1,\ldots 9.$  Three of the solutions for $b$ are $10$, $11$, and $12$.  The other seven solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

This can alternately be written as 30,000,003+10,000a+100b

1.30,000,003≡6(mod 13)

Thus, 10,000a+100b≡7(mod 13)

- 3a+9b≡7(mod 13)
- 3a+9b=7: No possibilities
- 3a+9b=20:No possibilities
- Now you have to realize that the RHS has to divide 3 by Bezouts lemma. So, 13x+7=3y
- 3y-13x=7
- 2x(mod 3)≡1(mod 3). Thus, x≡2(mod 3) and can be represented as 3a+2.
- 3y-13(3a+2)=7 so 3y-39a=33 and y-13a=11. y=13a+11. y also has to be less than or equal to 9. However, no solutions for y satisfy this.